# Update fields on Php

Tags: php

I don't know how to do it but hope anyone could help me about my program.

My program flows like this.

I have **search.php** - it will search unique id. I also have a button here, once submitted/loaded, it will echo all of the data on my index.php

**index.php** - this is where all data will be loaded. my goal is to update the fields. What i wanted to do is that test.php (contains my condition) will be read only after user click submits. because i tried to include it and place it on the top but it gives me error and not giving me the data that supposedly to be loaded. but when i tried to removed it, all data is successfully echoed on the textbox.

My test.php should be trigger once it was submitted.

**index.php**

```
<?php include 'test.php' ?>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
    Textbox 1:    <input type="text" name="txt1" value="<?php echo $txt1;?>">
    Textbox 2:  <input type="text" name="txt1" value="<?php echo $txt2;?>">
    Textbox 3:  <input type="text" name="txt1" value="<?php echo $txt3;?>">
                <input type="submit" name="btn1">
    </form>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
$txt1 = "";
$txt2 = "";
$txt3 = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $txt1 = $_POST["txt1"];
    $txt1 = $_POST["txt2"];
    $txt1 = $_POST["txt3"];
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, this should be what you want:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    include 'test.php';
}
?>
```

instead of

```
<?php include 'test.php' ?>
```

Comment: if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") will be duplicate once it is included or should i remove from the included file?

Comment: @NiCeMaRK I would let it stand there, better doing a check twice than not doing the check

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with Javascript and Ajax, but what you should first do, is give your input-elements unique names (now its txt1 in all of them) as well as the variables in test.php

Answer (score 0):

you  missed ; at the end of include statement.

```
<?php include 'test.php';?>
```

Thank you ....